# Can you use Fuel SDK with Python for the object TriggeredSendSummary

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, triggered-send, python

I know you can use ET_TriggeredSendSummary() method with the Fuel SDK using PHP but does anyone know if you can use it with Python? I don't believe so.

Furthermore, do you know when it will be available for Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **I know you can use ET_TriggeredSendSummary() method with the Fuel SDK using PHP but does anyone know if you can use it with Python? Dont think so:**

You are correct. The the class is missing from the `objects.py` file (You can search for it [HERE](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/blob/master/FuelSDK/client.py). Infact the only TriggeredSend soap method exposed is for TriggeredSendSummary :

```
class ET_TriggeredSend(ET_CUDSupport):
subscribers = None
attributes  = None
def __init__(self):
    super(ET_TriggeredSend, self).__init__()
    self.obj_type = 'TriggeredSendDefinition'

def send(self):
    tscall = {"TriggeredSendDefinition":self.props, "Subscribers" : self.subscribers, "Attributes": self.attributes }
    self.obj = ET_Post(self.auth_stub, "TriggeredSend", tscall)
    return self.obj
```

- **Furthermore, do you know when it will be available for Python?:** It will be available when someone gets frustrated enough to write one. Maybe that person could be you? `Make the Python Fuel SDK Great Again!`

Until you or some other star writes the class, you would have to make the call using the raw SOAP wrapper.

See example below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-24440876" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXX</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>TriggeredSendSummary</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Sent</Properties>
            <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>NotSentDueToOptOut</Properties>
            <Properties>NotSentDueToUndeliverable</Properties>
            <Properties>Bounces</Properties>
            <Properties>Opens</Properties>
            <Properties>Clicks</Properties>
            <Properties>UniqueOpens</Properties>
            <Properties>UniqueClicks</Properties>
            <Properties>OptOuts</Properties>
            <Properties>SurveyResponses</Properties>
            <Properties>Conversions</Properties>
            <Properties>UniqueConversions</Properties>
            <Properties>InProcess</Properties>
            <Properties>NotSentDueToError</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
               <Property>CustomerKey</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>TESTING</Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

For more information on making this SOAP call: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_a_triggered_send_summary.htm

Comment: thanks so much for your help on this! I will dive in and have a look! Appreciated